# non negative weights for embeddings

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, embedding

Is there a way to put constraint on weigths of embedding to be non negative?
I tried embeddings_constraint = tf.keras.constraints.NonNeg(),
but when I print weights some of them are negative.

```
Embedding(embed_input_dim, 
          self.embed_output, 
          input_length=embed_input_length,
          embeddings_constraint = tf.keras.constraints.NonNeg(),
          name = 'Embed_Request')(state_input)

print(self.model.get_layer('Embed_Request').get_weights()[0])

output:[array([[-0.03530975, -0.00357432, -0.02751002, ...,  0.01519774,
        -0.04078618,  0.03334286],
       [-0.0059206 ,  0.01738295, -0.020679  , ..., -0.03848881,
        -0.0269975 ,  0.025242  ],
       [-0.02481667,  0.03084642,  0.02665417, ..., -0.04804039,
        -0.01495937,  0.01566639],
       ...,
       [-0.04929062, -0.03186668,  0.04426355, ...,  0.0278681 ,
        -0.02907564,  0.00960131],
       [ 0.01267063, -0.00036066,  0.01877231, ..., -0.01406764,
        -0.01417869, -0.00672583],
       [ 0.00624986, -0.01128934,  0.0309539 , ...,  0.01535386,
        -0.02734694,  0.01445917]], dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure if I interpreted right, but from your snippet looks like you want embedings to be initialized as NonZero. Documenatation mentioned that thesee constriants are applied during training, so maybe you should train your network and look at embeddings after training?